# font-awesome , when use attribute the icon disapear

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have the following code:

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
```

but when I add an id and `onclick` attribute like so:

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-left" id="back" onclick="backNews();"></i>
```

the icon disappears.  Can anyone see the problem?

The icon re-appears if I remove the attributes

I have also tried to remove the `<i>` and replace it with a `<span>` tag, but no luck.

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: I would recommend attaching you javascripts events in javascript not via attributes. But if you absolutely have to then you could try something like this: `<span onclick="backNews();"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></span>`

Comment: Please check if your site's css by accident applies css rules for `#back` . Does it happen also if you use only `id="back"` **or** `onclick="backNews();"`?

Comment: @connexo you right, i have another css that applies on back and for, thanks very much :) , zgood thanks to you to

Comment: You're welcome. I've put it as an answer so you have the chance to show some appreciation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if your site's css by accident applies css rules for `#back`. Does it happen also if you use only `id="back"` **or** `onclick="backNews();"`? Does it happen if you change `id` like this

```
id="backNow"
```

?